# iOS 9: Using AVPlayerViewController Swift. (crossed out play button)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avkit

I'm having some trouble playing video content on both an ios device and in the simulator.

Goal: Stream a video from an online resource given here: 
[public video streams using hls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104301/hls-streaming-video-url-need-for-testing) using the `AVPlayerViewController`, just to learn how it works.

This consistently resulted in no errors being thrown, but the view controller presenting me with this view.

[image: AvPlayerViewController]

I decided to step back and test on a local resource, so I filmed a short screen capture in quicktime (.m4v) and saved it right to the project. This resulted in the exact same behavior with no errors reported.

Here is the code (`AVKit` and `AVFoundation` are imported ):

```
var playerVC : AVPlayerViewController!
var playerItem : AVPlayerItem!
var player : AVPlayer!
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let path = bundle.pathForResource("testVideos", ofType: "m4v")
    let url = NSURL.init(string: path!)

    playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: url!)
    player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
    playerVC = AVPlayerViewController.init();
    playerVC.player = player;

    self.presentViewController(playerVC, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        self.playerVC.player?.play()
    }
}
```

Seeing this warning when building to an IpadMini 4: `<CATransformLayer: 0x136ea1030> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect`

Xcode: Version 7.1
Targeting: iOS 9.0

**Update** 
Just some nasty constraint output from the AVPlayerViewController. I don't think this is contributing, but here it is:

2015-10-28 15:12:02.777 AVKitTest[4441:94545] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Comment: Well as a workaround, you can open and play a video with UIWebView, by calling its URL...

Comment: Appreciate the comment @Neo , but the purpose of all this is to learn about AVKit and the AVKitViewController.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it was something silly, just had to change:

`let url = NSURL.init(string: path!)
playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: url!)`

with:

`let url = NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: path!)
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: url)`

Comment: This was my problem too. Thank you!

Comment: T_T It took me almost 3 hours to find this solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not properly setting up AVPlayerLayer.

Look at the docs for AVPlayerLayer: "Returns an instance of AVPlayerLayer to display the visual output of the specified AVPlayer."

[image: example hierarchy from the AVFoundation Programming Guide]

Comment: Thanks for the post, you are 100% right if I were trying to set up and manage my own AVplayer but AVPlayerViewController is a part of AVKit that is supposed to manage all aspects of the player out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that there is not a video found in the supplied url. If you're using PHPickerViewController to load videos from the library you have to copy the files to a temporary disk location before playing them. See this [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652695) for more context.

Comment: The question states „no errors being thrown“. The questioner also posted the solution.